# PHP Ternary operator ('shorthand' if-statement)

Tags: php

I've reviewed the PHP Manual here: [#3 ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

but I don't understand why all three of these don't function as expected:

```
   $a = array('a','b','c');

    //works
    if(isset($a)){echo "yes";} else {echo "no";}

    //works 
    isset($a) == true ? $answer = "yes" : $answer = "no";
    echo $answer;

    //does not work
    isset($a) == true ? echo "yes" : echo "no";
```

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the ternary expression is an expression, its operands have to be expressions as well. `echo` is not an expression, it's a statement, it can't be used where expressions are required. So the last one doesn't work for the same reason you can't write:

```
$a = echo "abc";
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight.. so it seems like it differs a lot from the regular 'non-shorthand' If statement?  if ($a = "abc") "statement" else "statement"  vs. shorthand if-statement: statement: $a = "abc" ? "statement" : "statement" --- I guess after reading the documentation I thought they were very similar - but they aren't.

Comment: @Robert...this does infact work just fine...thanks:     echo isset($a) ? "yes" : "no";

Comment: @n8thanael The point is that you can use a regular `if` statement anywhere you can write a statement, and you can use a ternary expression anywhere you can write an expression.

Comment: And the body of an `if` can be any statement, while the operands of ternary can be any expression.

Comment: @Barmar Isn't `$answer = "yes"` a statement aswell?

Comment: @pmirnd Yes. An expression can be used wherever a statement is required, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the statement as,

`echo isset($a) == true ? "yes" : "no";`

The ternary operator doesn't exactly function like an if statement. The ternary operator does not execute the 2nd or 3rd expressions, it returns it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
echo isset($a) == true ? "yes" : "no";
```

Also no need to compare it with `true`:

```
echo isset($a) ? "yes" : "no";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use ternary operators you need to count operators precedence and associativity

you can rewrite your code to

```
echo isset($a) ? "yes" : "no";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last line of code should be like;

```
echo isset($a) == true ?  "yes" :  "no";
```